# Oracle parallel_max_servers hint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I am trying the example given in this blog in my laptop.
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/system-stats-2/

I get the values the same as mentioned in the blog, but when I use the parallelism hint, the system is not using the DOP, but  instead the same old plan is generated. I am not sure what I am missing or what values I did not set.

I have set my parallel_max_servers using the following statement:

```
alter system set parallel_max_servers=40 scope=both;
```

When I run the explain statement as:

```
 explain plan for select /*+ parallel(t1 5) */ max(n1) from t1;
```

I am still getting the same old plan as if no parallelism is used. Is there any other parameter I need to set to make my system use the parallelism.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the parallel hint, you don't need to specify a table name...just the parallelism quantity.  Like this:

```
 select /*+ PARALLEL (4) */ max(n1)
 from t1;
```

I confirmed that adding the table name, prevents parallelism from occurring in the execution plan.